# How do you connect to a SDE instance on EC2?

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, amazon-ec2

We are exploring using Amazon EC2 with ArcGIS Server - and none of us has any experience with it. The question "How can we, from within our intranet, connect to the remote SDE instance in the EC2 cloud?" has come up. Do you just do a direct connect and instead of the server name, use the IP of the EC2 instance? Something like `sde:sqlserver:<ip_address>` instead of `sde:sqlserver:HOU-SQLPRD10`? Surely connecting to the remote instance is possible, huh?

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for sde, but I did setup my postgresql/postgis database so that it could be accessible.  I did have to open up a port for the postgresql databases(for me, was 5432 and 5433).

This was a windows instance, so I think I also had to open them on the firewall (*not sure if I'm remembering that correctly*).

[image]

Maybe if you added an allowed tcp connection of 1433 to your instance's security group, it'll let you through to your sql server db.  Then you should be able to use the  `sde:sqlserver:<ip_address>` to connect.

Comment: Ports 1433 and 1434 should be open for SQL Server, but DO NOT OPEN THEM UP TO THE INTERNET.  (That's allowing 0.0.0.0/0 to connect).  Grant access to only your own externally-facing IP, then revoke it when you're done.

Comment: Good advice on the external IP.  I didn't think much about about it since I stopped the instances when I was done.  Can you modify the security group using the awstools and pop your external IP address in and out?

Comment: If you are pulling data for AGS you need that elastic ip open to 1433. If you need to manage from local you should add and delete that ip it as needed. there is no on off.

Answer (score 2):

I was just wondering if you had a preference for DC or 3 Tier?

As this will change the ports you will need to set up. I have not given this a try yet, but I was setting up a Geodata service using ArcGIS Server with Replication, as a result I connect to the local copy and replicate using the WAN protocols already set up on the EC2 environment.

I might have to give this a try

Here is some of the info I was using to set up

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_on_amazon_ec2/index.html#//00rq0000003n000000.htm

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_on_amazon_ec2/index.html#//00rq00000016000000.htm

Based on the last link looks like it does have the DC syntax in there.

CDB